# ASP.NET Core 6.0 Razor web pages: one edit page for 1:n relationship

Tags: asp.net-core, crud, razor-pages, one-to-many

I'm quite new to ASP.NET Core Razor web pages and have a question.
Within my web it is possible to create projects and assign 0 to many stakeholders (with few own properties) to it. Now I have created the model and database using EF for this. Then I have scaffolded the CRUD pages for projects object. Everything is fine so far.

In the normal approach I would create CRUD pages for stakeholders and then link them together, but this in this case user would need to create project first, then navigate to another page to add stakeholders which is quite ugly.

Is it possible to extend the create and edit pages for project with a control bound to a collection of Stakeholders and their properties to allow creating and editing stakeholders on the fly and then submitting them together.

Any ideas?

I'm currently following the approach to use JS on my edit/create project page to inject my data into DOM and forcing the databinding to retrieve my information, but if feels like I'm doing something not intended.

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a `ViewModel` that contains both the `project` Model and `stakeholders` Model, and use this `ViewModel` on the `Create` and `Edit` page.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple example, but I need to add a field in the `Project` model and the corresponding database to store the name or id of the `stakeholders` (I use the name in the example). You can refer to it:

Models:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string StakeholdersNames { get; set; }
}

public class Stakeholders
{ 
    public int StakeholdersId { get; set; }
    public string StakeholdersName { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, MyDbContext context)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<Project> project { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        project = _context.Project.ToList();
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<div><a asp-page="./Create">Create</a></div>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ProjectName</th>
            <th>StakeholdersNames</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var item in Model.project)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>@item.ProjectName</th>
                <th>@item.StakeholdersNames</th>
                <th><a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ProjectId">Edit</a></th>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Assuming you have fixed `stakeholders`, then you can use `select` tag to select (if not fixed `stakeholders`, you need to bind to `StakeNames` through `Input`).
Create.cshtml.cs:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;
    public CreateModel(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    [BindProperty]
    public Project project { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string[] StakeNames { get; set; }

    //Not required if there are no fixed stakeholders
    public List<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        Options = _context.Stakeholders.Select(s => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = s.StakeholdersName,
            Text = s.StakeholdersName
        }).ToList();
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        project.StakeholdersNames = String.Join(",", StakeNames);
        _context.Project.Add(project);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToPage("/index");
    }
}
```

Create.cshtml:

```
@page
@model TestApp.Pages.CreateModel

<form  method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.project.ProjectName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.project.ProjectName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">StakeholdersName</label><br />
        <select multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="my_multi_select1" asp-for="@Model.StakeNames" asp-items="@Model.Options"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Edit.cshtml.cs:

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;
    public EditModel(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    [BindProperty]
    public Project project { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string[] StakeNames { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet(int id)
    {
        project = new Project();
        project = _context.Project.Where(p => p.ProjectId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        String[] StakeholdersNames = project.StakeholdersNames.Split(",");
        Options = _context.Stakeholders.Select(s => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = s.StakeholdersName,
            Text = s.StakeholdersName,
            Selected = StakeholdersNames.Contains(s.StakeholdersName) ? true : false
        }).ToList();
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        project.StakeholdersNames = String.Join(",", StakeNames);
        _context.Project.Update(project);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToPage("/index");
    }
}
```

Edit.cshtml:

```
@page
@model TestApp.Pages.EditModel

<form  method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.project.ProjectName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.project.ProjectId" value="@Model.project.ProjectId" type="hidden" class="form-control" />
        <input asp-for="@Model.project.ProjectName" value="@Model.project.ProjectName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">StakeholdersName</label><br />
        <select multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="my_multi_select1" asp-for="@Model.StakeNames" asp-items="@Model.Options"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </div>
</form>
```

TestResult:

Index Page:
[image]

Create Page:
[image]

Edit Page:
[image]

If you're using MVC, you can put the `Project` and `StakeNames` in the same `ViewModel` as I commented, then use it in the View:

```
public class ViewModel
{ 
    public Project project { get; set; }
    public string[] StakeNames { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for your time and effort to build this.
So far I'm totally with you and understand your approach.

But what it makes my example to complex is the complexity of stakeholder object. Let say you have more attributes than just the name or id of stakeholders. Let say you would have available budget and role that you want to save as properties of stakeholder.
So it requires a more complex, specific control to add stakeholders with those values, edit them and remove them.

So the question is if it is possible but also if this make sense to have it on one page?

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Anatoli, can you provide your model structure and properties?